# Offsets to tree

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dom, data-structures

So I have a data structure that looks like:

```
{
  "text": "hello world!",
  "tags": [{"start": 0, "end": 4, "tag": "b"}, {"start": 1, "end": 5, "tag": "i"}]
}
```

And I want to turn it into something that looks like this:

```
[["b", [
   ["#text", "h"],
   ["i", ["#text", "ello"]]]]
,["i", ["#text", " "]]
,["#text", "world!"]]
```

(Yes, that is a sort of abstract representation of what it would look like as a DOM tree.)

I'm not really sure what the proper way to even start approaching this is. . . any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you would have to know that "i" is partially contained within "b" to use this? Just trying to make sense of why this could be a desirable thing to have

Comment: Yes, you know from the "start" and "end" offsets (the constraints are that the text from 0 to 4 must be a child of a "b", the text from 1 to 5 must be a child of "i").

Comment: Your example has unbalanced square brackets and it is not obvious how to fix it, can you balance it and then post again?

Comment: Just missing the last bracket. See edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the method of adding a new tag would be done through a process similar to depth first search. Originally the data structure would just be a single leaf node:

```
[
    ["#text", "hello world!"]
]
```

Adding the first tag would be splitting the only node so far into two nodes, one of which has the tag "b". In reality a new element is being added and the string of the only node is being made into a substring of what it was:

```
[
    ["b",
        ["#text", "hello"]
    ],
    ["#text", " world!"]
]
```

Generalizing the process, leaf nodes contain substrings of the original text and non-leaf nodes are tags. When adding another tag, a depth first search is performed while also maintaining the sum of the length of the substrings seen so far

When the search enters "b" in the above structure the substring sum length would be 0. After adding the length of that node's string ("hello") the substring length would become 5. Because the range of "i" overlaps 0 - 5 the "b" node must be split temporarily producing:

```
[
    ["b",
        ["#text", "h"],
        ["i",
            ["#text", "ello"]
        ]
    ],
    ["#text", " world!"]
]
```

However the depth first search is not complete for the "i" tag, the next node (labeled "#text") still must be split as well. The current substring length would be 5 upon entering that node and would become 12 after adding the that node's text (" world!"). "i" is within the range of 5 - 12 which is the condition to split the node producing:

```
[
    ["b",
        ["#text", "h"],
        ["i",
            ["#text", "ello"]
        ]
    ],
    ["i",
        ["#text", " "]
    ],
    ["#text", "world!"]
]
```

Note, the brackets are a little different from what you posted in your question. I think that the original bracket problem (mentioned in the comments) was not the last bracket